# Result Cache size in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Result Cache in Snowflake is quite useful.

One use case which I am trying is to run the User’s query post Batch Load in the datawarehouse so that the result is cached. And when after 2-3 hours when the Business Users would run the same query maybe using the most smallest warehouse the data will be returned from cache.

But I need to understand what is the volume capacity of the result cache. Can we get to know anyhow how much rows result cache can store.

Lets suppose a user query pulls a million rows. Will Snowflake store all the million rows in result cache. Or lets say 100 million rows.

Once the capacity is breached where will be the data stored. And how do we know the capacity and when it was breached

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical limit on the size of the result set cache. The limit is on time, which is 24 hours since the last use of a result set:

> Each time the persisted result for a query is reused, Snowflake resets
> the 24-hour retention period for the result, up to a maximum of 31
> days from the date and time that the query was first executed. After
> 31 days, the result is purged and the next time the query is
> submitted, a new result is generated and persisted.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html

Some additional considerations:

1. Running the same query does not guarantee use of the result set cache. There are 8 criteria that must be met, and even then it's not guaranteed to use the result set cache. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization
2. To guarantee using the result set cache, instead of running the same query within 24 hours, you can run `select * from table(result_scan('019caf93-0500...'));`
3. If you don't do any processing/filtering of the result set and just do a select *, it doesn't even need a running warehouse.
4. Note that if you run a query as in #2, if the data in the underlying table(s) changes, it will not change the results. Running the original statement that generated the result set again will do that (table changes is one of the 8 criteria in point #1), but will be less likely to reuse the results.
5. If you use the result_scan function, you can treat it like any table and join it with other tables, filter it, run functions on it, etc. Doing anything other than a simple unfiltered select will require a running warehouse. The warehouse size could possibly be substantially smaller than the one used to create the result set in the first place. For example, a complex query could digest results, and then someone may use the result set through the result_scan function to filter by rows or perform a simpler query against the pre-processed result from the main query.

Comment: Thanks Greg. So you are saying if my query returns 1 Billion Rows or Millions, it will stay in Result Cache. I was thinking there would be any limitation since Result Cache must be a seperate compute storing data in memory

Comment: It's not stored in memory. It's stored in object storage (S3, Azure Blob, Google Storage depending on cloud platform).